# Derby authentication error from Glassfish console but same credentials work from ij

Tags: java, glassfish, derby, javadb

I am trying, for the first time, to run a java EE 7 web app without an IDE and struggling through the learning curve. To keep things simple I have started with Glassfish 4.1 and Derby 10.11.1.2 which is what I used for development.

My current problem is an error configuring the connection pool on the Glassfish web interface. The error is 'Connection authentication failure occurred. Reason: Userid or password invalid'. However I have ij runing in a dos prompt and the Glashfish web console in Chrome.

from ij I can type 'connect 'jdbc:derby:localhost:1527/databasename;user=username;password=password'; and I connect fine and can look at tables, etc.  In the Glassfish web console I have name/value pairs with the same 'user' and 'password' values and it fails (exact same letters & case). I've tried changing the 'databaseName' property to make sure the error wasn't misleading and confirmed it has found the database correctly.

At face value, the error message seems wrong as I have proven from the DOS window. I am sure I am doing something wrong but am lost at how to diagnose it. Any suggestions?

---

More details of the steps taken: (Although I am sure some of these steps superceed others my lack of success has me in the mindset that redundancy is better than omission - all-in-all it seems much more complicated than it needs to be for a basic setup). My target is Wildfly but Glassfish documentation is better so I figured I would start there.

1. relevant Windows environment variables:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
   DERBY_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\db
   DERBY_INSTALL=%DERBY_HOME%
   JAVADB_HOME=%DERBY_HOME%
   GLASSFISH=C:\Program Files\Java\GlassFish-4.1
   Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%DERBY_HOME%\bin;%GLASSFISH%\bin;%GLASSFISH%\glassfish
   CLASSPATH=%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbynet.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbytools.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\derbyclient.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyrun.jar
   WILDFLY_HOME=C:\program files\java\wildfly\8.2.0.Final
   ```
2. sysinfo shows all the right paths and versions
3. Copied many of the derby jars from %derby_home%\lib to %glassfish%\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext per a post by BalusC. I think classpath duplicates this it but can't hurt
4. Started Domain 'asadmin start-domain' defaulting to domain 1
5. Started DB by changing directories and using java. Wanted to use 'asadmin start-database --dbhome *DB path*' but this always started the wrong version. Glassfish and JDK both package derby/javadb and I couldn't figure out how to upgrade Glassfish or start the correct version any other way

   ```
   cd \users\john\.netbeans-derby (root of the DB created by Netbeans)
   Java –jar “%derby_home%\lib\derbyrun.jar" server start
   ```
6. connect browser to 'localhost:4848' to create JDBC connection pool and resource

connection pool: pool name=connectionPool, resource type=javax.sql.DataSource, DB driver Vendor=Derby, introspect was not enabled (found very little documentation to explain what it is) - step 2 was left as defaults
editing connectionPool - enabled Ping on General tab to identify errors, Additional Properties tab: changed User to DB username, left other attributes as default, added... password=db password, databaseName=ClubScoring
errors were presented along the way which prompted setting each attribute. No error was presented for lack of URL but tested steps below with and without URL=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ClubScoring

jdbc resources. Added jdbc/ClubScoring, pool=connectionPool => selected and enabled

7. starting db from correct directory using 'asadmin start-database' does let the application find the correct DB but it crashes since the DB was created with version 10.11.1.2 and this command starts the Glassfish version of 10.10.2.0

Sorry for making this so long but I haven't found anywhere that lays out all of the steps in a simple fashion and figured the details would save time in the long run.

Comment: It sure sounds like you are connecting to different databases in the two cases. Try shutting down your Derby server to verify that you really are connecting to the server you think you're talking to.

Comment: @Bryan I assume you are right but I am not sure how to determine that. I've tried to show more details above which may clarify what I am doing wrong.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bryan stopping server received error that it wasn't running. Starting from wrong directory said DB did not exist. Only when started from correct place  was the error invalid user/password.  Interesting to note that I rebuilt the DB from Netbeans and although I got no further, I tested a different Glassfish admin password discovering that command line and Netbeans have personal cache's of credentials. I am sure you knew this but I didn't

Comment: I carried on and made the command line version the same connection attributes as the NB version and got it working. A little weird though... after deleting the redundant ones it still didn't work. I changed ServerName to serverName and Ping worked and the App as well. Case was inconsistent in other places so I didn't buy the fix and changed ServerName back - it still worked. Presumably one of the default attributes created by Glassfish was the problem but I don't know which. I deleted: TraceFileAppend, SecurityMechanism, Ssl, RetrieveMessageText, LoginTimeout, TraceLevel

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this issue today and found a solution:
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefattribsecmech.html

Basically the only security options allowable (as far as 10.14 is concerned) is 3, 4 and 9.

4 is the default and means "Just UserID". You would think this means that as long as a UserID is given, you could connect. But having both set appears to be an issue.

In order to use a (clear text) password and userID, you have to specify 3. It works also if the attribute is deleted or 0 as well but I don't think you get any security that way.