# connection pool won't connect due to invalid username or password

Tags: java, glassfish-4, netbeans-8

I have created a database within the netbeans client named Hotel with a username of username and password of password:

[image]

When I try creating a Connnection Pool in the Glassfish Domain Admin Console, I enter the username and password and name of the database, but when I go to ping it it says the username or password is invalid:

[image]
[image]

And I can't figure out why, Google hasn't helped much either

Comment: Try change "User" and "Password" to  lowercase?

Comment: @QuangTV I tried changing it to Username and that didn't help. I also tried putting it into lowercase but got the same result.

Comment: Would you be able to try to connect to the database with ij and see if credentials work.  Also check out this post  and the last comment maybe it will make sense to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423661/derby-authentication-error-from-glassfish-console-but-same-credentials-work-from

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the following Additional properties for the Connection Pool:

```
TraceFileAppend
SecurityMechanism
Ssl
RetrieveMessageText
LoginTimeout
```

Comment: Well they were already all off except for SecurityMechanism. How about you dig a bit further?